# Mysql : Inserting into table with reversed order

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with 3 Columns : `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3`

I want to insert into `Column1` and `Column2` only, and with `Column2` **first**, so i would write :

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column2, Column1 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 )
```

Can i do this?

Comment: You can insert into the table in any order you please. Just be sure that you want `Value1` should go into `Column2`

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Did you test it ? If you want to put "Value2" in "Column2" keep the same order in both columns and values. And make sure the undeclared columns can be nullable or have a default value set in your dbms. Hope this helps !